# asp.net MVC form POST working in Localhost but not working after publishing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, post, http-status-code-404, iis-7.5

HomeController.cs:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(LoginInfo login)
        {
            if (Request.Form["Submit"] != null)
            {
                string Username = login.Username;
                string Password = login.Password;

                ViewBag.Massage = "";

                if (Username == "Admin" && Password == "123")
                {
                    ViewBag.Massage = "Login Successfull";

                    return RedirectToAction("MSISDN","UnSub");
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Massage = "Please Enter Valid Login Information";                    
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Views/Home/Index.cshtml

```
<form name="myForm" action="/Home/Index"  method="post">
    <div align="center">
        <div style="color:red">@ViewBag.Massage</div>
        <br>
        <label for="Username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Username" id="Username">
        <label for="Password">Password:</label>
         <input type="password" name="Password" id="Password">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit"value="Submit">

    </div>
</form>
```

This code is works perfectly in my localhost. But when I publishe my project to IIS Server it is not working. It is returning -

> Server Error: 404 File or Directory Not Found.

May be it conflicts with my physical path and requested path. How to resolve this problem?? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Code is working properly after using an `tilde (~)` sign before action. 
For example:

> action="~/Home/Index"

After using this sign my code works properly. It reduce the conflicts between virtual path and physical path.

Answer (score 0):

The `action`'s url in the `form` tag may be wrong :

- If the url for display and post the data is the same, you can remove `action="/Home/Index"`
- If you want to specify the url, please use `action="@Url.Action("Index")"`

  - It will automatically resolve the Url.